# BootstrapVue: B-table item data not running formatter callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using the `<b-table>` component from [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) and trying to customize field output by using a [formatter callback function](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#formatter-callback). **The table data displays fine , but for some reason the callback function method `branchName()` is not being called and the value is not being formatted to the branch name instead of the branch id.**

I set up a codesandbox to demonstrate the problem: [code demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/btable-print-branch-name-3nv6n)

The goal of the method is to return the name of the `branch` item. However, only the `branch_id` is being returned. In other words, the record row under the `Branch` table column should say `ACME10` and not `10`.

My file named `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-table striped hover :items="userProfiles"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userProfiles: [
        {
          uid: "3",
          branch: 10
        },
        {
          uid: "1",
          branch: 20
        },
        {
          uid: "2",
          branch: 13
        }
      ],
      branches: [
        {
          branch_id: 13,
          branch: "ACME13"
        },
        {
          branch_id: 10,
          branch: "ACME10"
        },
        {
          branch_id: 20,
          branch: "ACME20"
        }
      ],
      fields: [
        {
          key: "branch",
          formatter: "branchName"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    branchName(value) {
      const name = this.branches[0].find(branch => value === branch.branch_id);
      return name;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use slots to implement custom behavior like. For more information https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#scoped-field-slots

Here is how you could implement your code

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-table striped hover :items="userProfiles">
      <template slot="[uid]" slot-scope="data">{{ data.item.uid }}</template>
      <template slot="[branch]" slot-scope="data">{{ branchName(data.item.branch) }}</template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

Method:

```
branchName(value) {
  const branch = this.branches.find(branch => value === branch.branch_id);
  if (branch) {
    return branch.branch
  }

  return ""
}
```

Comment: Yes, but for some reason I get the following console error using slots method: `main.js:26 Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'branch' of undefined
Info: render`

Comment: When I do your above slot method, it wont' work, however, when I just do: `{{ branchName(data.item.branch) }}` in the slot template it will spit out json. For some reason I can't attach `.branch` to that method ..it gives the console error

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Which line is it exactly? I created a codesandbox btw to show it is working: https://codesandbox.io/s/btable-print-branch-name-1gte0

Comment: I presume the data is in de example is not the real data probably the method is returning null in a certain case

Comment: For this example purpose I added the .branch as the method was returning an object.Normally I solve this in the method itself

Comment: Some record data in my real data returns `null`. Is that an issue?

Comment: Yes it is, I updated my code so It will also work wil null values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198968/discussion-between-redshift-and-dreijntjens).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OPs original question (why the formatter function was not being called):

In your `App.vue` file you are missing binding your `fields` definition array to the `fields` prop of `<b-table>`.  Try this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <b-table striped hover :items="userProfiles" :fields="fields"></b-table>
  </div>
</template>
```

If `<b-table>` isn't passed a field definition array, it will peek at the first row's item data and grab the field names that it finds, and then generates its own internal `fields` definition (just the field keys and humanized labels)

Answer (score -1):

try this in your template

```
<template v-slot:cell(name)="data">
      <router-link :to="/route/${data.index}">
        {{ data.value }}
      </router-link>
```